# Automatically Changing Image URLs to Relative URL

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

We are using Kentico 13 with MVC websites that consume the data. Our marketing team occasionally attaches images into rich text areas, and they have a relative URL to Kentico (like: `<img src="/getmedia/guid/filename.png" />`). However, when this gets rendered on our main website, it'll be a bad reference (because the relative URL is trying to be relative to our MVC website.

I tried just changing the image URL to include the fully-qualified url (ie: `<img src="https://cms.website.com/getmedia/guid/filename.png" />`, but Kentico changes it back to a relative URL when I save. How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Duplicated on https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-text-area-relative-urls-for-images